# How to add dropdown menu for every list item

Tags: html, css, frontend, navbar

i want to add a dropdown menu for every list item in my navbar when i hover over it
I've tried bunch of techniques but every time it ends up ruining the formation or overlaps my list items

```
<style>
li{
margin-left: -2px;
display: inline-block;
font-size: medium;

}

a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:rgb(90, 88, 88);
}

a:hover{
    color: black;
}

/* Lowernav */
.lowernav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: sticky;
    padding: 0 60px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100;
    background-color: white;
}

.lowernav-firstpart {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 65%;
    align-items: center;
}

.lowernav ul{

    vertical-align: baseline;

}


.lowernav ul a{
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.lowernav li{
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    
    text-align: center;
}

.lowernav li:hover{
    background-color: rgb(246, 247, 249);
}



/* button */
.lowernav button{
    padding: 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(13, 82, 255);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
</style>
```

My HTML

if you want to run this code make sure to add the logo image. Dimensions (132x30)

```
<div class="lowernav">
            <div class="lowernav-firstpart">
                <img src="logo.svg" alt="">
                <nav>
```

here i need to add the dropdown menus for every list item

```
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <button><a><b style="color:white;">CONTACT US</b></a></button>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to use a placeholder image I recommend https://picsum.photos/ and my favourite.. Fill Murray https://www.fillmurray.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need a nested list, maybe something like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list__item {
  position: relative;
}

.sub-list {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.list__item:hover {
  color: red;
}

.list__item:hover .sub-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.25rem;
  left: 0;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">
    <span class="list__text">One</span>
    <ul class="sub-list">
      <li class="sub-list__item">Apple</li>
      <li class="sub-list__item">Orange</li>
      <li class="sub-list__item">Pear</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <span class="list__text">Two</span>
    <ul class="sub-list">
      <li class="sub-list__item">Pinnaple</li>
      <li class="sub-list__item">Avocado</li>
      <li class="sub-list__item">Salad</li>
      <li class="sub-list__item">Tomatoes</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <span class="list__text">Three</span>
    <ul class="sub-list">
      <li class="sub-list__item">Pumpkin</li>
      <li class="sub-list__item">Kiwi</li>
      <li class="sub-list__item">Banana</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```